# CSS and JS file references in JSP getting error

Tags: java, jsp

When a JSP is created and need to add a reference, as jQuery or CSS, in the JSP file in a determined file folder, if we reference as below, when deploy the file an error in the Browser is showed as below.

> An error occurred trying to load the resource.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<link href="/lib/js/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

I tried this variations without success:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery-3.5.1.js" /></script>
```

However, when proceeding with a configuration in the Properties for the application in the menu Deployment Assembly (Web Deployment Assembly) and add direct the path for the CSS or JS reference it will work.

JSP information:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
```

Path information:

> WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/css and WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/js

Is this file reference in the project right? How this Web Deployment Assembly reference works? Always is necessary Add a Deployment Assembly when create a new folder for JS or CSS files in a specific folder?

Comment: Please realize  that a JSP  sends a HTML page to a client browser.  Your browser will try find the scripts that you reference.    The   WEB-INF folder in your web app is not accessible  to the public.  The WEB-INF is for private use of your web app. Please move your javascript files out of there .  Place your js folder  into  the WebContent folder.

Comment: @rickz Thank you for the reply. I moved the path outside of the WEB-INF folder and re-write the address with "./". After that, the reference worked well without the Deployment Assembly configuration.